# Is the javascript newline character passed as \n into vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Is the javascript-newline character '\n' passed on to vbscript when using ajax. Tried to replace it but was not found.
In the parent HTML page, I have this textarea:

```
<textarea id="text1"></textarea>`<br />
<button id="btnSub" onclick="submitText">Submit</button>`
```

From that, I have the jquery ajax submission

```
   function submitText()
{
  var a = $("#text1").val();
  $.post("form1.asp",{a:a});
}
```

In form1.asp, I have this code:

```
Dim text1 = formatTextArea(Request.Form("a"))

Public function formatTextArea(v)
 Dim text: text = v
    if Instr(1,text,"\n") <> 0 then
        text = Replace(text,"\n","<br \>")
    Else
        text = "Not found"
    End if
    formatTextArea = text
End Function
```

Each time it shows "Not Found", I have tried replacing '\n' with 'vbcrlf' in the function but the result is the same - "Not found".

My question is, is the javascript newline character '\n' changed when submitted or what, because it doesn't seem to exist when submitted via ajax jquery.

Comment: Post your code. I'm not really sure how to answer this because there is no context.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript (and many other languages) you can use [escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) to put special characters into string literals. VBScript does not have this feature.

So your line

```
if Instr(1,text,"\n") <> 0 then
```

does not search for newlines, but for sequences of "\" and "n". Depending on whether your data encodes End Of Line by "\r\n", "\n", or "\r", you should use

```
if Instr(1,text, vbCrLf) <> 0 then
```

or

```
if Instr(1,text, vbLf) <> 0 then
```

or

```
if Instr(1,text, vbCr) <> 0 then
```